# intellij inspections does not show javac warning of non-varargs call of varargs method

Tags: intellij-idea

I am currently in the process of setting up IntelliJ Inspection Profile so that it can point us potential problems in Editor. But I am not finding a way to make it point out javac warning of "non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;".

Consider the following snippet:

```
public static void varArgsMethod(Object ... arr) { }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    varArgsMethod(args);
}
```

In Eclipse, method call, `varArgsMethod(args)` is underlined (with a jagged yellow line), but in IntelliJ this does not seem get caught by the Inspection. Although, when I do compile the file in IntelliJ, the warning does show up in the "Message Panel":

[image]
Anything I can do to make this warning pointed out in the Editor itself? (like any Inspection warning with a yellow mark and highlight)

Answer (score 0):

This exact warning is currently not available as an inspection. What is available is the `Confusing 'null' argument to var-arg method` inspection. It reports on a single `null` as an argument to the last parameter of a varargs method. This problem is reported by the same javac warning you reference. So I guess this is about half of what you want.

Another inspection you may want to take a look at is `Confusing primitive array argument to var-arg method`. This reports a similar problem, which is not reported by javac or Eclipse.